# How can I detect a URL really exists despite a 301 or 302 redirect?

Tags: python-2.7, url

I am looking to write a function in python to confirm the existence of files that might exist on a remote server.

Some of the downloads I am checking, however, are behind 301 or 302 redirects.

I have tried using the requests module as follows:

```
def exists(path):
    r = requests.head(path)
    return r.status_code in(200,301,302)
```

However, this returns a True if a file request is 301/302 redirected regardless of whether the target file actually exists. Just a 200 result returns a False, even when a request is successfully redirected to a file that exists.

I would be most grateful for any advice anyone may have on the best way to do this.

Comment: I'm not with you. What I am saying is that if I check the existence of a file using a URL that provokes a redirect but the actual file itself does not exist at the target URL, it still returns a true.

e.g. say I call "http://a_test_address/old/filename.mp3" and this redirects to "http://a_new_address/filename.mp3", regardless of whether filename.mp3 exists, because my path triggers a redirect on the server, it returns a 301/302 and the function says my file exists, which it might not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the steps outlined in [diveintopython](http://www.diveintopython.net/http_web_services/redirects.html) (copied and slightly cleaned bellow) if you want to use stdlib only. Otherwise, use something more nuanced (like Mechanize) to follow redirects.

```
class SmartRedirectHandler(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler):     
    def http_error_301(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers):  
        result = urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler.http_error_301( 
            self, req, fp, code, msg, headers)              
        result.status = code                                 
        return result                                       

def http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers):   
    result = urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler.http_error_302(
        self, req, fp, code, msg, headers)              
    result.status = code                                
    return result   

>>> opener = urllib2.build_opener(SmartRedirectHandler())
>>> resp = opener.open(urllib2.Request("http://www.redirector.com/whatever")
>>> resp.url
'http://www.redirector.com/actual/resource.mkv'
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you are currently using is working as it's designed to. I'd suggest using another function:

```
import urllib
page = urllib.urlopen('http://google.com')
page.geturl()
--> 'http://www.google.com/'
```

This tool can help you eliminate the redirects.